# remove pre-pending "data" from json string

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am making a call to a third party API, and the json string I get back looks like this:

```
{
  "data":[
          {"id":197567,"name":"101","url":"http://www.foobar1.com"},
          {"id":197568,"name":"102","url":"http://www.foobar2.com"},
          .....
          {"id":197569,"name":"120","url":"http://www.foobar20.com"}
        ],
  "offset":0,
  "pageSize":2,
  "count":20
}
```

And then I have a class `FoorBarURIs`:

```
private class FoorBarURLs
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}
```

So, I don't care about the `offset` or the `pagesize` or the `count`.  All I need is the data inside `data`.

Given that what I'm starting with is just a string, how do I extract that list from `data` so I can do this:

```
List<FoorBarURLs> myList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FoorBarURLs>>(???)
```

Comment: Why not create a model with `Data`, `Offset`, `PageSize`, and `Count`?  I get that you just want `Data`, but why not just make the wrapper model anyway?

Comment: @Amy, yes, I can certainly do that.  But I was hoping to avoid it if possible.  Just more code that isn't needed if there is another way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a temporary JObject

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(json)["data"].ToObject<List<FoorBarURLs>>();
```

Comment: what is JOBject?

Comment: @CaseyCrookston `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject`

Comment: That worked!  Perfect.  I'll mark as the answer as soon as it lets me